# Angular 1.4: How do I force update of directive within a ng-repeat with filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does one force a directive to update if it nested in a ng-repeat which has a filter?

Input Box

```
<input type="text" class="name-search" ng-model="search.text">
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="user in users track by $index | filter:search">
<profile-photo user="user"></profile-photo>
<span>{{ user.name }}</span>
<li>
</ul>
```

As I type in the input box, the users filter properly but the profile-photo directive doesnt have the proper user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Heres a dumbed down Plunker of my actual code.  If you start typing, you will notice that it filters but the image doesnt update.

https://plnkr.co/edit/FWD2bFdIh7jQa5aqdkjr[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FWD2bFdIh7jQa5aqdkjr)

Comment: Can you please provide the ode for the profile photo directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link's function code only executes once, when compiling the directive. After that, `scope.photoUrl` does not change even if you change the user, because you're not `$watching` the value. You can add a watch, or directly, use this in the template

```
ng-src="{{user.photoUrl}}"
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo!  I actually had a watch but I got it confused with another property.  Thank you for the extra pair of eyes!

Comment: Hey Gonzalo, Im running into some inconsistencies with my code.  Based on your suggestion, are you recommending a watch on the users collection, or a user in the users collection? if it is the singular(user), how do you add a watch to it?

Comment: I added a watch on the user in my ProfilePhoto directive, which worked :) thank you again!

Comment: create a question on SO and provide code and what you've done